# Why does this Nginx config result in “rewrite or internal redirection cycle”

Tags: nginx

I cannot figure out why this error is happening: "rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html""
in nginx.conf

```
user www-data; worker_processes auto; pid /run/nginx.pid; 

events { worker_connections 768; # multi_accept on; } 

 http {

 sendfile on; tcp_nopush on; tcp_nodelay on; keepalive_timeout 65; types_hash_max_size 2048; # server_tokens off;

 # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64; # server_name_in_redirect off;

 include /etc/nginx/mime.types; default_type application/octet-stream;

 ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

 access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log; error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

 gzip on; gzip_disable "msie6"; 

 upstream api { server 127.0.0.1:8080; }

 server { listen 0.0.0.0:80; root /open-ethereum-pool/www/dist; index index.html index.htm;

 server_name localhost;

 location /api { proxy_pass http://api; } 

 location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; }

 }

}
```

Comment: Does the file `/open-ethereum-pool/www/dist/index.html` exist and is it readable by the process running `nginx`?

Answer (score 18):

The issue is related to your config

```
server {

    listen 0.0.0.0:80; 
    root /open-ethereum-pool/www/dist; 
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Change

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

to

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
```

This will make sure that when even `index.html` in not there you get a 404 and not a internal redirection cycle

Currently what is happening is below when you browse `/index.html`

It becomes

```
try_files /index.html /index.html/ /index.html;
```

Now if `/index.html` doesn't exist then your fallback option (last parameter for try_file) is `/index.html`. This creates internal redirection cycle. So create the index.html file and the use try_files below way to avoid such issues

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
```

Comment: this tric worked for me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time You would want to resort to a fancy 404 not just default nginx error page.

Change

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

To

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /error.html;
```

Obviously you will have to place this error.html in your root directory, or even

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /error404/error.html;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got that error because `index.html` file was missing at that root directory.
After I added `index.html` file, it started working normally.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this directory ;

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled (Debian dist.)
```

there is file that named as default and this file linked to your website conf. even you change your `nginx_conf` this file be valid for nginx server

Answer (score 0):

On my side the sites-available in path

> */etc/nginx/sites-available/project-name*

did not have a linked in file in the sites-enabled in path.

> */etc/nginx/sites-enabled/project-name*

Creating this file on the sites-enabled by running the command fixed my issue

> ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/project-name /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/project-name